# Can't add android platform to ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to add Android to my Ionic App, so I type

```
ionic platform add android
```

in my console and the only output what I get is and no android is added

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Saving platform to package.json file
```

My enviroment variable are:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/xxx/android-sdk"
export ANDROID_TOOLS="/Users/xxx/android-sdk/tools/"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/Users/xxx/android-sdk/platform-tools/"
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/xxx/Documents/Projekte/goparse/bin:
            /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/deployd/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:
           /usr/texbin:/Users/xxx/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin:/Users/xxx/android-sdk/tools:/Users/xxx/android-sdk/platform-tools"
```

and my ionic info looks like this:

```
Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.8.5
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.5.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.1.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 1.9.0
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.4
Xcode version: Xcode 6.3.2 Build version 6D2105
```

Have somebody the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I dont know why but I have to specified the android version, like this:

```
ionic platform add android@4.0.2
```

This works for me.